# Compare complex objects with scala

Tags: scala

I have ip addresses and ip ranges. I already parsed them into such representation:

```
val patternIP(i1, i2, i3, i4)  
val patternRanges(i1_1, i1_2, i1_3, i1_4, i2_1, i2_2, i2_3, i2_4)
```

I would like to compare and find out if an `ip` is in a `range`, eg: 
`6.207.95.225` is in a range of `6.207.94.74-6.207.97.36`
Could you, please, suggest to me the most functional way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert IPs into their numerical representation.
After that your task is just to check if one number is in range within given boundaries.

Something like:

```
  case class Ipv4Address(value: Int) extends AnyVal

  def apply(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int): Ipv4Address = {
    Ipv4Address((a & 0xff) << 24 | (b & 0xff) << 16 | (c  & 0xff) << 8 | (d & 0xff))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexey! But what does method `uint` do? I don't see it in `Byte` class

Comment: I've updated my answer, but really, `uint` is just a function defined as `a & 0xff`. This is because Byte in Scala is signed, therefore it cannot be >127. With this trick we can convert a signed value into unsigned, but we should widen the type because values >127 will not fit Byte.

Comment: Thanks again! Could I ask last question, what is `value` argument stands for?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `value` is just a field in a case class wrapping it (and a constructor argument as well). I mean you could just return an Int without having a case class, but I personally prefer to be explicit in my types.